# Get open filename is killing ifstream

Tags: c++, winapi, ifstream, getopenfilename

I have a problem with GetOpenFileName.
Before calling GetOpenFileName method WriteData is working.
WriteData have a simple file check procedure:

```
ifstream inFile(FileName.c_str());
if (!inFile.is_open()) return false;
```

ofn dump:
[image: Dump]
And after calling GetOpenFileName its always false. But before calling GetOpenFileName its working fine.

```
while (!lang->LoadLang(config->getLanguagePath()))
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrFile = config->getLanguagePath();
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.lpstrTitle = "Select the language file";
    ofn.nMaxFile = 255;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Language file\0*.lng\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == 0) return 0;
    config->WriteData(KEY_LANG, ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what the struct looks like after the `GetOpenFileName` call?

Comment: Check it out. Question is updated.

Comment: That looks like a valid filename, so whatever is going wrong seems to be in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: No, i mean, after calling GetOpenFileName i can't open any file via  ifstream.

Comment: I tried a simple test and as expected it worked fine for me.  What does `config->getLanguagePath()` return?  What does the `config->WriteData` function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I tried to use WinAPI function OpenFile to open file, and got error code 2 (file not found).
And now i fixed it.

```
char buffer[255];
GetCurrentDirectoryA(255, buffer);
OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
ofn.hInstance = hInstance;
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.lpstrFile = config->getLanguagePath();
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.lpstrTitle = "Select the language file";
ofn.nMaxFile = 255;
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Language file\0*.lng\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == 0) return 0;
SetCurrentDirectory(buffer);
config->WriteData(KEY_LANG, ofn.lpstrFile);
```